# Expand Windows 10 system drive by using RAID

Tags: windows-10, raid

I have Windows 10 with 500 GB SSD that is used as the system drive C:.

Sorry for a newbie question, but I just need to expand it somehow to 1GB preferably without loosing the data.

I have another two SSDs of 250GB, but I am not sure they are exactly of the same size. Is it possible to construct 1TB logical disk by adding them?

Another option is to buy another 500GB SSD.

What kind of RAID do I need? 0, 1 ... 5 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add them, but there will be not data protection in case one of them fails. You have to convert them to dynamic disks in the disk manager before you can merge them.

I would just get 1 tb ssd, keep the OS and etc on the 500gb, and have plenty of room for actual data on the 1tb drive.

This contains complete instructions.
https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-one-large-volume-using-multiple-hard-drives-windows-10

How to combine multiple hard drives into one large volume

It's important to note that you will erase the content of the hard drives participating of the Spanned or Striped volume, as such make sure to backup the data before proceeding.

```
1. Use the Windows key + X keyboard shortcut to open the Power User menu and select Disk Management.

2. Right-click the hard drive volume and select Delete volume.

3. Click Yes to confirm the deletion of the current volume and all its content.
Repeat steps 2 and 3 on the hard drives you want to combine.
Right-click the unallocated space of the drive and select New Striped Volume (or New Spanned Volume).

4. Click Next.

5. Select the additional disks, one by one, and click Add.

6. Click Next.

7. Leave the default drive letter assignment and click Next.
Make sure the file system is set to NTFS, allocation unit size is set to default, and choose a volume label.
Check the Perform a quick format option.

8. Click Next.

9. Click Finish.

You'll be prompted to convert the hard drive from basic to dynamic, click Yes to complete the task.
```

WARNING ALL PARTITION will be WIPED.

administrative command prompt

```
diskpart
list disk
select disk # (whatever it is)
clean
exit
```

done

Comment: Converted two disks to dynamic disks, what next? See the screenshot https://slogpost.ru/video/misc/dyndisk.png . How to merge them?

Comment: Looks like I can't delete the system volume.

Comment: @Dmitriano see updated answer

Comment: Looks like it is not possible to expand the system volume (C:\) in this way, right? Or I misunderstood something?

Comment: @Dmitriano  I think your going to have to merge the 2 500gb ssd that you said you had.  You can use **mklink** to form a hard link from a folder on your C drive to the new volumes.  I think both disks have to be totally blank to start with.

Answer (score 1):

To increase storage, you need RAID 0 - but if any one of the drives fails on RAID 0 you lose **all** the data from **all** the drives.

Better to buy a new 1TB & keep the 500 as a backup drive.